# JQuery / JavaScript: Replace element class if it has img child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace the class `Col1` of `.nav li` if it has a child element with image, or a div with class `NavItemHolder`, and change the class to `Col2`

```
<ul class="nav">

   <li class="Col1">
    <a class="lvl1 parent" href="#/">Option1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>SubOption1</li>
        </ul>
   </li>

   <li class="Col1">
    <a class="lvl1 parent" href="#">Option2</a>
        <ul>
                    <li>
                    <div class="NavItemHolder">
                        <div class="NavItemImage">
                            <a href="#">
                            <img src="/menu.jpg"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="NavItemDesc">
                            <a href="#">SubOption2</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </li>
        </ul>
   </li>

</ul>
```

I tryed:

```
$('.nav li:has(img)').removeClass('Col1').addClass('Col2')
```

but this adds the class Col2 to the inner li items also

Comment: just check whther it is working: find() $('.nav li').find('img').removeClass('Col1').addClass('Col2')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the space in your initial selector, it's finding any `li` that's a descendant of `.nav`.  Use the below instead for direct children:

```
$('.nav>li:has(img)').removeClass('Col1').addClass('Col2')
```

Comment: Thanks James, I've overlooked that.